# refresh page on success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the javascript code below to load recrefresh.php when the page initially loads. When the function ajaxvote is executed I want the following div to refresh:

```
<div class="recrefresh"></div>
```

I tried adding the following after success:, but the div doesn't refresh after executing ajaxvote:

```
$.get('recrefresh.php', function(data) {
  $('.recrefresh').html(data);
});
```

Entire Script:

```
<div class="recrefresh"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('recrefresh.php', function(data) {
  $('.recrefresh').html(data);
});
</script>

<script>
$('.ajaxvote').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default link action
$.ajax({
 url: $(this).attr('href'),
 success: function(data){
alert("Vote Saved.");
$.get('recrefresh.php', function(data) {
  $('.recrefresh').html(data);
});

 }
});
});
  </script>
```

Comment: $.get() works on document load?

Comment: Yeah the php file is called and I see the table on page load. If I use the function ajaxvote then the div doesn't refresh on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //run function here
  refreshMyDiv();

  //click event for dynamically generated elements
  $('.recrefresh').on('click' , '.ajaxvote' , function(){
     //run function inside click
     refreshMyDiv();
  });
});

// function to refresh the .recrefresh div
function refreshMyDiv(){
  $.get('recrefresh.php', function(data) {
    $('.recrefresh').html(data);
  });
}
  </script>
```

Comment: @michelle glad it helped you .. but just an advice to simple the job to yourself don't try to repeat the same code every time .. just make a function with the code you want and run the function anywhere up to your need .. Very Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue take parent div to `<div class="recrefresh"></div>` because direct div does not load sometimes so wrap this `div` with other `div` say for ex.

```
<div class="recrefresh_parent"><div class="recrefresh"></div></div>
```

and use `recrefresh_parent` to refresh table.
There is the way to refresh or load div after ajax call:

```
$('.recrefresh_parent').load("recrefresh.php .recrefresh_parent");
```